# I want to override page.tpl.php to work for all pages or custom urls

Tags: 7

If i override page.tpl.php to page--front.tpl.php which is working for only front page of site. But i want that overrided .tpl file should work for other urls as well. how can i create ? is there any other filename suggestion which i can use ?

Comment: More than likely whatever theme your using it will be page.tpl.php

Comment: okay, but i have created .tpl file in my module folder and that i want to use in all pages and don't want to implement that file in current theme, just want to override

Comment: basically i have created a module which contains .tpl files and those are overriding the theme folders .tpl files and i couldn't manage to override page.tpl file which is working for all pages.

Comment: Your `page.tpl.php` will work for all pages except the ones that have their own page template defined, for example `page--front.tpl.php`. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions#s-page-frontinternalpathtplphp and also see https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/template-theme-hook-suggestions#s-add-a-pagetplphp-depending-on-content-type for adding your own template suggestions based on content type for example. From there it's just a small step to have templates suggested based on the current URL.

Comment: Okay. thank you Leigh and @leymannx

Comment: Solved by creating Sub-theme, i just overrided all those pages which i want. instead of creating module i created sub-theme and solved.